# SqlAlchemy: Is there a performance difference building queries over multiple lines or functions?

Tags: performance, sqlalchemy

How efficient is sqlalchemy if I use several query objects, lines of code, or functions to build my final query? Is there a performance hit as it executes each step, or is it smart enough to figure out what's going on and only execute the final query?

e.g. say I have code that does this:

```
get_shiniest_robots(self, polish_date):
    """Get robot_ids for robots with recently polished spikes."""
    return session.query(Robots.robot_id).filter_by(spike_polish_date > polish_date)
```

Then I have another function that does

```
get_dullest_robots(self, polish_date):
    """Get robot_ids for robots that have not been polished lately."""
    return session.query(Robots.robot_id).filter_by(~Robots.robot_id.in_(get_shiniest_robots(polish_date))).values(Robots.robot_id)
```

Will get_dullest_robots() send two queries to the database instead of one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a performance hit as it executes each step, or is it smart enough to figure out what's going on and only execute the final query?

Query has well defined points at which SQL is emitted:

1. when you iterate over it, that is, "for item in query:"
2. When you call `.all()`, `.one()`. `.first()`, `.scalar()`, `.values()`, `.count()`, and sometimes `.get()`.
3. most other methods are what we call "generative", which is also known as "method chaining".  The methods listed out at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html should give a hint, if not explicitly, if you're getting back a new `Query` with additional state, or if you're getting SQL emitted results back.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this for yourself by turning on sqlalchemy echoing and running the queries. When you connect to your database pass the `echo` parameter with something like `create_engine(dbstring, echo=1)`.

Then run your queries.

get_shiniest_robots:

> INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT t_robots.robot_id AS
>   t_robots_id FROM t_robots JOIN t_spike_maintenance ON
>   t_robots.robot_id = t_spike_maintenance.robot_id WHERE
>   t_spike_maintenance."spike_polish_date" > ?

get_dullest_robots

> INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT t_robots.robot_id AS
>   t_robots_id FROM t_robots JOIN t_spike_maintenance ON
>   t_robots.robot_id = t_spike_maintenance.robot_id WHERE
>   t_robots.robot_id NOT IN (SELECT t_robots.robot_id AS
>   t_robots_robot_id FROM t_robots JOIN t_spike_maintenance ON
>   t_robots.robot_id = t_spike_maintenance.robot_id WHERE
>   t_spike_maintenance."pike_polish_date" > ?)

You can see sqlalchemy is creating a subquery rather than executing two separate queries, which seems normal. It is only executing the SQL once.

Comment: This is what I've found from my own research but I'm interested to see if I'm wrong or if anyone has a better answer.